# NLP: Are hashtags tokenised?

Tags: natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, word-embedding

I am exploring a potential NLP project. I was wondering what generally is done with the hashtags words (e.g. `#hello`). Are those words ignored? is the `#` removed and the word tokenised? Is it tokenised with the `#`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word including Hash tag need to be tokanised. It has a special meaning and given a context. The word by itself has a different meaning.

Comment: So have they been encoded during training by models such as GPT or BERT?